# Lottie animation scale type in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, lottie

Lottie animation view simply can sets scale type by `android:scaleType="centerCrop"`.

Is there a way to set LottieAnimation composable scale type like XML?

Answer (score 4):

You can send the scale type as param of  **LottieAnimation**

```
  LottieAnimation(
                        composition = composition,
                        modifier = Modifier
                          .align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally),
                        contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
                        )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `clip` modifiers for the same. If not, custom modifiers can be created. Check out the official compose layout codelab to learn it